# Integrator is missing in render Sampling tab?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I've seen Integrator in sampling in many tutorials and in sampling articles and [blender manuals](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/sampling.html?highlight=integrator) but I can't find it in my properties. I am new to blender so is there some preference setting to enable for this?
I am using blender 2.93.6

[image: Image of my Properties Editor]
[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is Blender 2.9 and not Blender 3.0? I can see the *[Sampling > Integrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwbIp.jpg)* dropdown selection box right above* Sampling > Render* in Blender 2.93.6. But according to this release notes (https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.0/Cycles) => *"Branched path tracing was removed. We recommend using adaptive sampling to automatically allocate more samples where needed."* - see section *Removed Features and Compatibility* at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Blunder yes I am using 2.93.6 , I edited the question with version image.

Comment: Hmm, I have the same version, same hash. The only difference I can see is that you use the GPU while I have to use the CPU for render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option is not available if you set your render device to Optix.

Use None, CUDA or OpenCL (not sure about OpenCL but I can't test it) to enable the option. go to Edit > Preferences > System and expand Cycles Render Devices.

[image]

Comment: this is old info for old versions.

Comment: @JKCapeTown Hello ! Thanks for the feedback. AFAIK integrator is available by default ? Not sure it warrants a downvote since the answer still stands for version 2.93. Make sure you are using Cycles render engine.